# Render title/legends as html with django crispy forms

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I got a form with tabs, and an accordion under a tab, like this:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
            TabHolder(
                Tab(
                    'Title',
                    HTML('{% load i18n %}<h4>{% trans "This works well" %}</h4></br>'),
                    Accordion(
                        AccordionGroup(
                            HTML('I am HTML'),
                            'a_field',
                            ),
                    ),
                ),
            )
```

While `HTML()` works when rendered after the first argument, when used as the first argument it just returns a `<crispy_forms.layout.HTML object xyz>`.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-9011" href="#crispy_formslayouthtml-object-at-0x3d6ea90">&lt;crispy_forms.layout.HTML object at 0x123456&gt;</a>
```

How do I get it to render properly?

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for template tags and filters, but to use HTML for the title of a tab or accordion group, you can use `django.utils.html.format_html`:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Accordion(
        AccordionGroup(
            format_html('This is <em>html</em>'), 
            'a_field',
        ),
    ),
)
```